# why I got nilError while saving managedObjectContext?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, view, swiftui

I have some views that transfer information.
Finally i want to save the data but i get "nilError".

And how can I have the sheets faded in from right to left?

I'm new at this but I hope someone can help.

Model:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

public class Test: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var message: String?
}
```

.xcdatamodel:
Attributes: "name" and "message" both String and "Class.name": test, "Module": Current Product Module, "Codegen": Manual/None
(Sorry, I'm not allowed to upload images)

Views:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ThirdView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    
    let name: String
    let message: String
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            Text(name + ": " + message)
            Button("Dismiss"){
                self.saveThis()
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveThis(){
        let newEntry = Test(context: self.managedObjectContext)
        
        newEntry.message = self.message
        newEntry.name = self.name
    
        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    
    let name: String?
    @State private var message: String = ""
    
    var body: some View{
        List{
            TextField("Message: ", text: $message)
            
            Button("Next"){
                self.showingSheet.toggle()
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet){
                ThirdView(name: self.name!, message: self.message)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NewEntry: View {
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Show Sheet"){
            self.showingSheet.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet){
            SecondView(name: "Fritz")
        }
    }
}
```

... I have one other Entity in my xcdatamodel and some other model class to save other information and there I have no problems.
It might be stupid, but is it possible, that I can only have one of these managed objects?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `.sheet` modifier introduces new view hierarchy so you have to set any required environment value to view in sheet explicitly (in this case context), like

```
}.sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet){
    ThirdView(name: self.name!, message: self.message)
       .environment(\.managedObjectContext, managedObjectContext)
}
```

and so declare it in

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
...
```

Comment: okay, sounds good, but now it says: "value of type ThirdView has no member 'managedObjectContext'" in func saveThis how to solve this?

Comment: Your SecondView is also shown in sheet so it should be done same for it as well.

Comment: I forgot to declare the env var in "NewEntry", thanks a lot!